# Error installing rails, failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, makefile, debian

I know there is a couple of topics about that, but the reason I create a new one is that it still doesn't work for me ...

So here is my configuration :

```
ruby -v : 1.8.7
gem -v : 1.8.21
```

And when I try to make

```
sudo gem1.8 install rails
```

I have the following error :

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: not found


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.6.6/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

I'm running on Debian 6.0.4 Squeeze.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have make command, as your output says. In debian install package *build-essential*

Answer (score 0):

I think gcc or c-compiler isn't install or not writen in environment path, I've got same problem while installing rails, but after Install gcc, I can install rails very well.